# Fresh Ruby/Gems install on Centos 6.5

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've just installed Ruby 1.8.7 and RubyGems 1.3.7 via 'yum install ruby'/'yum install rubygems' on a Centos 6.5 box. Right off the bat, just running gem gives me this:

> /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- timeout (LoadError)
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:7
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:7
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
>       from /usr/bin/gem:9

My googlefu has failed me in identifying this issue, too. Has anyone encountered this sort of problem and/or know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Remedied the situation by using RVM to install Ruby 2.2.0. Gem works now.